# auto-complete option does not work - Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, cygwin

To use auto-complete option, for writing C syntax, I have written below elisp code in `.emacs` file.

### [image]

Here are the files in the directory.

### [image]

But, amidst the typing of C syntax, I do not see the auto-complete option to select the syntax.

I am expecting the auto-complete option, as shown below, when I type `while` keyword. In my case, I do not see below behavior.

### [image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The question is unclear. Show a step-by-step recipe, preferably starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say way you see and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: @Drew I have edited my question

Comment: Run `(ac-config-default)` after `require`ing auto-complete.  You actually don't need the `require` if you installed with the package manager (I highly recommend using the package manager).  You may want to add additional ac sources specific to C, like `ac-c-headers`.

Comment: @jpkotta In addition to above two lines shown in my query, I wrote `(ac-config-default)`, . Auto complete facility does not work

Comment: You're going to have to do better than "doesn't work".  Are there any errors?    Are you doing this with `emacs -Q` (start emacs without any nonstandard config, to isolate the problem)?  I just tested, and all you need (besides `load-path`, etc.) is `(ac-config-default) (global-auto-complete-mode 1)`.

Comment: @jpkotta In the above query, Please see the updated code I wrote in `.emacs`. This code does not work

Comment: You'll notice that I put the function calls in a different order than you did.  And I won't ask again: are there any errors?  You can see them with `C-h e`.